# Eliminar objeto de Array en PHP

Tags: php, poo

estoy practicando con ejercicios de objetos en php y no puedo encontrar la forma de eliminar un objeto de un array. El tema es el siguiente: Se me pide que cree una clase llamada Prestamo que tiene como atributos el código, el nombre, el apellido y el monto.Tengo que crear un array donde pueda subir diferentes objetos a través del _POST y también tengo que poder eliminar objetos usando el boton "remover" y aca es donde me entra la duda porque probé con el foreach usando unset, array_splice, etc y si no tiraba error no daba ningún resultado.

Ahí pongo el código para que se entienda mejor:

```
class Prestamo{

private $codigo;
private $nombre;
private $apellido;
private $monto;

public function __construct($codigo, $nombre, $apellido, $monto){
    $this->codigo = $codigo;
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
    $this->monto = $monto;
}
public function setCodigo($codigo){
    $this->codigo = $codigo;
}
public function getCodigo(){
    return $this->codigo;
}
public function setNombre($nombre){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
}
public function getNombre(){
    return $this->nombre;
}
public function setApellido($apellido){
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
}
public function getApellido(){
    return $this->apellido;
}
public function setMonto($monto){
    $this->monto = $monto;
}
public function getMonto(){
    return $this->monto;
}
    }
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="codigo">Ingrese  el codigo del cliente</label></br>
        <input type="number" name="codigo" id="codigo" required></br>

        <label for="nombre">Ingrese la nombre del cliente</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required></br>

        <label for="apellido">Ingrese apellido del cliente</label></br>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" required></br>

        <label for="monto">Ingrese el monto</label></br>
        <input type="number" name="monto" id="monto" required></br>

        <button type="submit" name="subir" id="subir">Subir</button>
        <button type="submit" name="remover" id="remover">Remover</button>
        <button type="submit" name="salir" id="salir">Salir</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
  include_once("prestamo.php");
  if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
     session_start();
  }
    if(isset($_POST["subir"])){
      $prestamoOb = new Prestamo($_POST["codigo"], $_POST["nombre"], $_POST["apellido"], 
      $_POST["monto"]);
      $_SESSION["presta"][]= $prestamoOB;
      foreach ($_SESSION["presta"] as $valor){
        echo "<hr><ul>";
        echo "<li>codigo: ".$valor->getCodigo($_POST["codigo"])."</li>";
        echo "<li>nombre: ".$valor->getNombre($_POST["nombre"])."</li>";
        echo "<li>apellido: ".$valor->getApellido($_POST["apellido"])."</li>";
        echo "<li>monto: ".$valor->getMonto($_POST["monto"])."</li>";
        echo "</ul><hr>";
    }
```

}
?>

Comment: Buenas, Rodri, ¿has probado a almacenar el objeto empleando un indice? Por ejemplo el código. O algún identificador único. De forma que puedas hacer el unset haciendo referencia a ese índice/codigo. Algo como $_SESSION["presta"][$prestamoOb->getCodigo()] = $prestamoOb; para añadir y unset($_SESSION["presta"][$prestamoOb->getCodigo()]) para borrar.

Comment: Por cierto, en tu último extracto de código aparecen los métodos get con un argumento, lo cual no coincide con lo que has puesto de la clase Prestamo. ¿No deberían aparecen sin argumento ninguno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de borrar un elemento de un array es array_splice($arrayentrada, desde, cuantos).
En esta caso el array de entrada es $_SESSION['presta'], cuantos supongo que 1 y desde pues tienes que buscarlo.
Doy por supuesto que cada Prestamo tiene un código único. Así que yo buscaría en el array $_SESSION['presta'] el índice correspondiente al código del préstamo que quieras borrar y luego aplicaría la función array_splice().

```
//buscar índice
$valor = -1;
foreach($_SESSION['art'] as $key=>$valor){
    if($valor->getClave() == $_POST['clave']){
        $ind = $key;
        break;
        }
 }
//Si se ha encontrado el código del artículo
if ($valor>=0){
    $res = array_splice($_SESSION['presta'], $ind, 1);
    print_r($_SESSION['presta']);
    }
```

Otra forma en la que podrías resolver este supuesto es guardar los prestamos en un array asociativo, es decir, $_SESSION["presta"][$_POST['clave']] = objetoPrestamo. De esta manera luego puedes usar unset($_SESSION["presta"][$_POST['clave']]. De esta forma te ahorras la búsqueda y te aseguras que cada clave es única.